# PHP encrypted $_GET variables throws Fatal error: Allowed memory size exhausted

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

Why if i put

```
w3Zho+mol6yATVfhqi8KkQ==  ("ln -s")
```

Then this doesn't work:

```
function cdecrypt($data) {
    $key = '000000';
    $iv = '1234567812345678';
    $decrypted = openssl_decrypt($data, "aes-128-cbc", $key, 0, $iv);
    return $decrypted;
}

$c = urlencode($_GET['c']);
$comm = cdecrypt(urldecode($c));
echo $comm;
```

Error:

```
 Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted
    (tried to allocate 3095496193 bytes) in /var/www/ai/service.php on line 7
```

but if i change encrypted string to

```
 QYRiSyTwk4r6Js6jNVlziQ== ("ln -ls")
```

it shows decrypted string (in this case `ln -ls`) just fine?

Comment: The key needs to be 16 bytes. Not sure about other issues, though.

Comment: Could it be something to do with restrictions on the characters allowed in variable names, or does this not affect using strings as variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can edit your php.ini file you should increase the memory limit higher then 3095496193 bytes by adding or modifiying that line on your php.ini file:

```
memory_limit = 300M
```

or a higher limit.